# Regex, Finding a single quote enclosed by single quote

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am maintaining an old system that have saving issue when a string contains a single quote.

For example these will fail:

```
"update table set column2 = 'O'Connell', column3 = 'O'Riordon' where column1 = 1"
"insert into table (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7) values('O'Reilley','state, postcode','',1,2,'O'Riordon')".
```

So far I've came up with this working vbscript regular expression

```
([,=(]\s*'[^']*)'([^']*'\s*[,)\s])
```

Is it possible to write a vbscript regular expression without using the header [(|=|\s|,] and trailer [,|)|\s]?

Thanks.

EDIT: Fix the posted regex to remove | from header and trailer.
The regexp is used as follows

```
regexp.replace("string","$1''$2")
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that the correct syntax for these character classes would have been `[,=(]` and `[,)\s]`, and that it's puzzling why the latter contains `\s`: Why do you want to remove them? And if they are gone, how will you tell where a match begins or ends?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks for the correction, the trailing \s is to match the Update statement "Column3 = 'O'Riordon' ".

Comment: Exactly, so if you remove that part of the regex, how else would you know where a match starts or ends? You've obviously got malformed data, so if there's anybody who can tell what rules need to be followed to salvage this, it's you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of works only if the string that contains the single quote never contains whitespace. In that case, you can search for

```
\B'([^'\s]*'[^'\s]*)'\B
```

**Explanation:**

```
\B        # Assert that there is no alphanumeric character before...
'         # the opening quote
(         # Match and capture...
 [^'\s]*  # Any number of non-quote/non-whitespace characters
 '        # One quote
 [^'\s]*  # Any number of non-quote/non-whitespace characters
)         # End of capture group 1
'         # Match the closing quote
\B        # Assert that there is no alphanumeric character afterwards
```